# Writing a Simple APEX Class

Tags: apex, class, lead-conversion, lead-assignment

Sorry, this could be a simple question, but I'm struggling to find a way to modify a code and convert a lead into an existing Account. I'm trying to do this by using the setAccountID method. The ID would be a Lookup account Field which is already populated, but when I try to set this lookup field in the method, I get the error message "This variable does not exist"

Hope you can help me w this!

```
public class ConvertLeads
{     @InvocableMethod   
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)  
    {         
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];    
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();    
        for(id currentlead: LeadIds){                
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();    
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                               
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
            Leadconvert.setAccountId(Linked_Account__C);//Linked_Account__C is the field where I retrieve the ID of the account which the lead will convert
            Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);
            MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);    
        }                  
        if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty())
        {            
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);       
        }    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here

```
Leadconvert.setAccountId(Linked_Account__C);
```

You need to query for the Leads before you enter the for loop

```
Map>Id, Lead> leadsById = new Map<Id,Lead> (
    [SELECT Id, Linked_Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: leadIds]

for (Id currentLead: LeadIds) {
  ...
  LeadConvert.setAccountId(leadsById.get(currentLead).Linked_Account__c);
}
```

Unlike triggers, invocable methods only have in context whatever is passed in the argument list